# Data flow where db2 serves as a proxy

Tags: proxy, db2

I have db2 client and db2 server/instance in two different network locations. Network with db2 instance can't be reached directly from the client network. How can I achieve, that db2 client can send data to db2 server ? Is it possible to setup db2 server/instance in between acting as a proxy ?

Comment: You need to provide a direct path between client and server. This is something to ask in a networking arena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install the Db2 Server product as a "proxy". Such a functionality is called "Db2 Connect".
Consider the following architecture.

HOST1, PORT1, DBNAME - your database server.
HOST2, PORT2 - your "proxy" Db2 Server instance without any local databases.

On HOST2:
db2 catalog tcpip node I1 remote HOST1 server PORT1
db2 catalog db DBNAME at node I1

Now you can access the database DBNAME on HOST2 using PORT2 from your clients (instance based or instance-less) as it was a real database managed by the db2 instance on HOST2.

Comment: This still requires network access from the proxy to the target server, and from the client to the proxy, so either the proxy is on the client network (not reaching the target) or on the target network (unreachable from the client).

Comment: The proxy server must be on both networks of course. Do you think it's impossible?

Comment: If it were possible, why would one bother setting up a proxy instead of putting the client itself on both?

Comment: The answer is obvious - because it's probably impossible to put both client and server on the same network.

Comment: With appropriate tunnelling , there is no need for Db2-connect.